# Comma before "As if"

Tags: commas, conjunctions

In which of the following cases would a comma be used before the as if clause?  Does this follow the restrictive/non-restrictive rule?

> - "Hmmm," giggled the girl as if hearing the funniest joke she had ever heard.
> - He paused for awhile as if he were rearranging his thoughts in his head.
> - He was holding a jar of bright jelly with pink dots floating through it as if they were curious astronauts in space.

Comment: What do you mean by *the restrictive/non-restrictive rule*?

Comment: @TrevorD: The OP means the difference between "People who pop gum are annoying" and "Those people, who by the way like to pop gum, are annoying". In the first case the set of people in question is restricted by the who-clause, whereas in the second it's not. Not that it makes any sense in the context of "as if"

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան Thanks. I assume *pop gum* is an Americanism - I've never heard that expression.

Comment: @TrevorD: Do watch the "Chicago" musical, specifically [the Cell Block Tango](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrrz54UtkCc) :)

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան Nope! Never heard of it! I don't watch any musicials and veeery few films!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would put a comma before *as if* in **all** of them.

In many cases, the use of commas comes down to personal choice or clarity.

For the reader, it is helpful to use a comma to indicate where to pause when reading, which in turn often adds to the clarity of the sentence and may obviate the need for the reader to re-read it a second time.

I found that, without the commas, I did have to 'think twice' about the sentences - and that commas would help.

Comment: When a dependent clause is restrictive, it means that the clause can not be taken out of the sentence without changing the meaning of the sentence.  A non-restrictive dependent clause can be added or omitted without changing the essence of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon whether "as if" introduces an essential or nonessential clause. Therefore, I would place commas in the first two examples but not the third.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a comma  in the third example makes it sound (to me) as if the "as if" clause modifies "holding" rather than "floating".